# Matplotlib backend lets me either have interactive window or use pyplot.close('all') withouth an error

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, python-3.4

I am using ipython with python3.4 via a virtualenv and had to change matplotlib's backend in order to have the interactive plotting window show up. But when I try to plot not in the ipython shell but import a script that does the plotting for me, I can not use pyplot.close('all') (therefore multiple open windows are lingering in the back that can be open with plt.show())without getting the error:

```
can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"
```

I can get rid of this behavior by explicitly using matplotlib.use('agg') but then pyplot.show() is of course not working anymore. I guess i fundamentally do not understand how to choose an appropriate backend. When I use matplotlib.get_backend() it gives me 'TKAgg'.

Is it possible to be able to close windows in a script while being able to open interactive windows or is this behavior generally not wanted?

Comment: Which version of iPython are you using? Both myself and some colleagues had similar problems after upgrading to iPython 5.0.

Comment: yep that is the version I am using right now. Can not say for sure if that is the first time this problem appeared but that is possible. Any quick and dirty fix for this problem? I am now setting the backend to agg in any plot script and using TkAgg in a different shell.

Comment: I downgraded to 4.2; I've heard from several colleagues that they had similar problems, so I'll wait until ipython 5 (and/or the combination with matplotlib) is a bit more mature.

Comment: hmm the downgrade does not solve the problem for me. What does matplotlib.get_backend() give you?

Comment: In fact it happens even in without using ipython....ah well. Not the worst thing that can happen but still annoying. Pretty tedious to have multiple windows open to 'play' with the data